# How to scale up the values of each vectors

Tags: r

I have this eigenvector matrix of 100 vectors. The problem I have is that the value of the vector is very low almost zero (for average e-10)!! The following is an example of one vector:

```
0.000000245023212264631
-0.00000000928673421733024
-0.00000000702744206187778
-0.0400022257147745
0.000715047161691289
0.000178299491594312
0.000000000000000111022302462516
-0.000000000000000444089209850063
-0.0000311452059972295
0.000000928320962476081
0.00025873217452001
-0.0000073255984986786
0.000226706852668388
-0.00000637215108697076
-0.00000741641656228371
0.000000000466042723561714
0.000000000279056699407741
-0.00000000926312312226756
0.00000000000000000000000000323117426778526
0.000000000000000000000000000403896783473158
-0.0366691252097418
-0.0305829466924761
-0.0300306491122465
0.99163522436172
-0.0000000033133072963138
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000331297544425818
-0.0000100525189687
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
0.000000100784783009722
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.0000000033133072963138
-0.0000000033133072963138
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
-0.00000000339576544864114
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000229274956160153
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000229274956160153
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
0.000000000128704479996649
```

I want to know if I can somehow scale up each vector so that I get to have the values are close from 1 as possible without destroying the property of eigenvectors (for instance, 0.01 instead of 0.0000001). The following is the code I use:

```
library(igraph)
M <- data.matrix(test)
G <- graph.data.frame(M, directed = FALSE)
L <- laplacian_matrix(G, normalized = FALSE, weights = NULL, sparse = FALSE)
options(scipen=999)
df <- data.frame(eigen(L)) 
df[,1] <- NULL
write.table(df[,1], file = "~/test.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this messes with the properties at all but how about something like...

```
test <- rnorm(100, mean = 0.00000000001, sd = 0.00000000002) # fake small set
test <- ifelse(test<0, test*-1, test) # removed negatives
scaledtest <- test/(max(test)+test[which.max(test)]/10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of an eigenvector x of matrix A is such that Ax = cx for some eigenvalue c. So if you scale up x to say kx then your eigenvalue must be c/k to satisfy the equation. So you can scale your eigenvectors however you want by a scalar but the corresponding eigenvalue will be multiplied by the inverse.

I wouldn't recommend it if this feeds into any additional calculations because the errors you are introducing could be huge.